# How to get HashMap labels based on selected List

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I need your assistant in getting the labels from a `HashMap` based on the items which are available in my `ArrayList`. The String ArrayList has the values ["CE1","CE2"] and its initialization in the bean is:

```
private List<String> selectedCertificates = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Currently, it has two values.

The HashMap code is:

```
Map<String, String> certificates = new HashMap<String, String>();
certificates.put("CE1", "AAAA"); 
certificates.put("CE2", "BBBB");
certificates.put("CE3", "CCCC");
```

My issue is that I need to get the labels ("AAAA","BBBB") in a different `ArrayList`based on the available keys in the above list , so I can display the labels in a dataTable.

Comment: Try `for (String key:list) differentList.add(certificates.get(key));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
   Map<String, String> certificates = new HashMap<String, String>();
    certificates.put("CE1", "AAAA"); 
    certificates.put("CE2", "BBBB");
    certificates.put("CE3", "CCCC");
    List<String> selectedCertificates = new ArrayList<String>();
    selectedCertificates.add("CE1");
    selectedCertificates.add("CE2");

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();


    for (String certificate : selectedCertificates) { 

        String certificateValue = certificates.get(certificate);
        result.add(certificateValue);
    }



    System.out.println(result);
```

In this example I have CE1 and CE2 as selected certificates. Then i get the value for those keys in the map.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, You have a subset of the map keys in a separate arraylist, and you want only the values of the map corresponding to those keys.
If that's the case, do (assuming this arraylist of yours is called keySubSet)

```
for(String keyInSubSet : keySubSet) {
   selectedCertificates.add(certificates.get(keyInSubSet));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this satisfy your requirements:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String selectedCertificate : selectedCertificates) {
    result.add(certificates.get(selectedCertificate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<String> selectedCertificates = new ArrayList<String>();
    selectedCertificates.add("CE1");
    selectedCertificates.add("CE2");
    Map<String, String> certificates = new HashMap<String, String>();
    certificates.put("CE1", "AAAA"); 
    certificates.put("CE2", "BBBB");
    certificates.put("CE3", "CCCC");

   List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(String k : selectedCertificates){
       if(certificates.containsKey(k)){
          valuesList.add(certificates.get(k));
       }
   }
```